# Why can't you check a single instance of a variable for two logic conditions in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison, conditional-statements

Why do I have to do this in PHP:

```
if ($var > 0 && $var < 700) {
    // DO STUFF
}
```

Why can't I do this:

```
if (0 < $var < 700) {
    // DO STUFF
}
```

IS THERE A WAY TO DO THAT WITHOUT HAVING TO STATE `$var` TWICE?

Comment: because that's how the authors of php wrote it. ranting here wont help

Comment: ^^^^^ `if(in_array($var, range(1, 699))` but I wouldn't.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, does it work for doubles or numbers just a bit smaller than 700? (Eg 699.9999)

Comment: @MarcinSzwarc:  Maybe maybe not, floating point arithmetic is strange and `range()` will show that.  `print_r(range(699.9997, 699.9999, .0001));` shows `Array
(
    [0] => 699.9997
    [1] => 699.9998
    [2] => 699.9999
)` on my system, however my `if` was not a serious solution, obviously.  Why search an array of possibly thousands, millions or billions of numbers?

Comment: PHP mostly copied C expression syntax, and C doesn't have this kind of operator either. I think the only popular language that does it is Python.

Comment: Questions about why a language is designed a particular way are not really appropriate here, the answers are generally just speculation and opinion.

Comment: @rtfm I'm not ranting, just want to know why and if there is an alternative.

Comment: @barmar, Thank you for the explanation; however if not the place to ask such questions, where would you ask such a question? Thanks.

Comment: you may want to look up what TYPING IN ALL CAPS MEANS

Comment: @Bryce I don't think there's anywhere to ask questions like that, other than contacting the language designer directly. He'll probably say what I said, that he copied the syntax from C.

Answer (score 0):

Condition `0 < $var < 700` is evaluated left to right and gives us something like this `true < 700` which is a bit strange - you can't compare int and boolean

You can't do that typing `$var` only once